# Directional derivative of a function using the definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have the following function and I have to find the directional derivative for a general vector $v=(v_1,v_2)$ using the definition.
$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
\frac{e^{xy}-1}{x} ; x\not= 0 \\
y ; x=0
\end{cases}$$

I tried to write the limit, but I can’t manage to factor it in some way so I can get rid of the h.

Comment: Are you allowed to use l'Hospital?

Comment: @amsmath Yes I can, but how can I use it in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\neq 0$ the derivative is

\begin{align}
\partial_vf(x,y)
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+hv_1,y+hv_2) - f(x,y)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{e^{(x+hv_1)(y+hv_2)}-1}{x+hv_1} - \frac{e^{xy}-1}x}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x(e^{(x+hv_1)(y+hv_2)}-1) - (x+hv_1)(e^{xy}-1)}{hx(x+hv_1)}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{xe^{(x+hv_1)(y+hv_2)}-xe^{xy} - hv_1e^{xy}+hv_1}{hx(x+hv_1)}\\
&\overset{LH}{=} \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{xe^{(x+hv_1)(y+hv_2)}(v_1y+v_2x+2v_1v_2h)- v_1e^{xy}+v_1}{x^2+2v_1h}\\
&= \frac{xe^{xy}(v_1y+v_2x)- v_1e^{xy}+v_1}{x^2}
\end{align}

And for $x=0$:

\begin{align}
\partial_vf(0,y)
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(hv_1,y+hv_2) - f(0,y)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{e^{hv_1(y+hv_2)}-1}{hv_1} - y}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{hv_1(y+hv_2)}-1-v_1yh}{v_1h^2}\\
&\overset{LH}{=} \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{hv_1(y+hv_2)}(v_1y+2v_1v_2h)-v_1y}{2v_1h}\\
&\overset{LH}{=} \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{hv_1(y+hv_2)}[(v_1y+2v_1v_2h)^2+2v_1v_2]}{2v_1}\\
&= \frac{v_1^2y^2+2v_1v_2}{2v_1} = \frac{v_1y^2+2v_2}{2} = \frac 12v_1y^2+v_2.
\end{align}

Comment: Wow, thanks!! And one more question. Since in the case that $x\not = 0$ the function is differentiable, will I get the same result by doing: $<\triangledown f, (v_1 ,v_2)>$ right?

Comment: @Facu50196 Exactly. I just checked it and it's the same result.

Comment: Great! Thanks!!